# Does google app engine use python 2.7.0 or 2.7.1?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, google-app-engine, pycrypto

What python version does app engine use?

This is related to problems I'm having on mac osx with getting pycrypto to work. Because the python version now in mac is 2.7.1. When Google says the python version for app engine is '2.7' do they mean precisely 2.7.0? Or is python 2.7.1 okay too?

Can this cause problems for my local install of pycrypto? ( which I installed with pip: `sudo pip install pycrypto==2.6` )The pycrypto library works correctly, but it somehow messes up app engine running a development server. The logging doesn't show all errors or logs which I expect to appear there.

Comment: How about asking the google app engine support team?

Comment: SO provides a faster answer

Answer (score 0):

> When Google says the python version for app engine is '2.7' do they mean precisely 2.7.0? Or is python 2.7.1 okay too?

Any subversion of python 2.7 works. 2.7.0 works, but I have used 2.7.6 and 2.7.10 extensively as well. So I'm sure that 2.7.1 will work too.

> Can this cause problems for my local install of pycrypto? ( which I installed with pip using: 'sudo pip install pycrypto==2.6' )The pycrypto library works correctly, but it somehow messes up app engine running a development server. The logging doesn't show all errors or logs which I expect to appear there.

I know you have asked about this before but I will give you an other (better) way to include pycrypto in your appengine project.

In your app.yaml, specify the following:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"  # or "latest", or "2.3"
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27 for more info about which libraries are supported by appengine and how you can import which versions.

Comment: Yes, the pycrypto library is correctly included in the app.yaml, this was so before, during and after the problem I have described in this question and others.

Comment: @iciPiracy Well, to answer your question: any problems with pycrypto messing up the logging are surely not related to any difference between python 2.7.0 and python 2.7.1

Comment: @iciPiracy you're welcome. Please give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you're asking the question which inspired your title, about python verson 2.7.x, as a way to get insight into your *actual* problem, which is related to pycrypto. Tim's answer dealt with the question of which sub-versions of 2.7.x are supported.

It appears you're using both the app.yaml libraries stanza *and* pip to get an instance of pycrypto. So:

Is the pip-installed `pycrypto` residing on your dev-box somewhere like `/usr/local/lib/python-2.7`, or is it in the app's folder, specifically?

When the dev-server is running, is it possible your python path has it using the  `pycrypto` installed by pip on your system, with that `pycrypto` being a different version than the one in production? This might cause different behaviour on the dev-server vs. production.

---

...All this said, it still seems odd, as Tim has pointed out, that you should see a disruption to logging based on this. What is it you're logging, and are you using any exception handling which might be dropping the responsibility to log?

Finally, is there a setting when running the dev-server which you can use that would [enable more verbosity](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/)? Try that to see if you can raise the logging level enough to make the exceptions you're looking for visible.

These are my thoughts so far on how to get out of your jam.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Right now I have installed pycrypto with PIP and it is indeed in python 2.7 site-packages. I have no pycrypto folder or library in my own app folder.

I have tried raising the level to debug but this changes nothing.

Comment: I have tried both using pycrypto 2.3, 2.6 and 2.6.1. The app crashes on 2.3 because I'm using features not supported in that version. Both 2.6 and 2.6.1 give the same problem which is that logging seems to stop working ( inconsistently however ).


I have experimented by placing logging lines before and after every python import statement in every python file, and logging stops working after right the pycrypto import. This means my own 'logging.info('')' lines and any errors which app engine dev server should show in the log.

Comment: Check the logging level by `previousLevel = logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()`, `logging.getLogger().setLevel (logging.DEBUG)`, `logging.info ("%d > %d?" % (previousLevel, logging.INFO))`.

Comment: If `previousLevel` is greater than `logging.INFO`, then you the logging level (really a threshold, with the sequence `{ DEBUG, INFO, ... }` increasing numerically) has somehow been set higher than INFO.